# How to select each value of array

Tags: arrays, database, postgresql, unnest

Consider following case

```
Table : tab1
id    serial      primary key
arr   int[]
```

Now I want to select each value of `arr`.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT arr FROM tab1) AS tab2
```

I need kind of iteration in array.

e.g.

```
id    arr
-----------------------------
1     [1,2]
2     [5,6,8]
```

So I could get result as

```
arr      val
-------------------------------
[1,2]    1
[1,2]    2
[5,6,8]  5
[5,6,8]  6
[5,6,8]  8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-array.html) for that:

```
WITH array_data(id,arr) AS ( VALUES
  (1,ARRAY[1,2]),
  (2,ARRAY[5,6,8])
)
SELECT arr,unnest(arr) AS val 
FROM array_data;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I've got well but here you have all you need

```
select id,
       unnest(arr),
       array_to_string(arr,','),
       array_length(arr, 1)
from array_data;
```